# Sonar: Replication/high availability or clustering solutions

Tags: sonarqube

Does SonarQube (Sonar) support replication/high availability solution?  My goal is to have a failover SonarQube instance for if/when there's hardware failure on the machine the current instance is running on.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no support for clustering with SonarQube.

What you can do for the moment is only to have prepared virtual machines that you can start when there's a failure on the SonarQube instance. Obviously, there will be the startup time during which the service won't be available - but that's the best you can do for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

[SonarQube Data Center Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/data-center/) provides [high availability](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/High+Availability+Plugin). It is not available with the free Community Edition or the lower tier paid editions.